# Can integration relate real and complex numbers? eg, considering $\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$ vs $\int\frac{dx}{(1+ix)(1-ix)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers

We all know that
$$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}x+C$$
Let's evaluate this a bit differently,
$$\int\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int\frac{dx}{(1+ix)(1-ix)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(1+ix+1-ix)dx}{(1+ix)(1-ix)}$$
$$=\frac{i}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)+\mathbb C$$
but that must mean
$$\tan^{-1}x=\frac{i}{2}\ln \left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)+\mathbb C$$
Plugging in $x=0$, we get
$\mathbb C=0$
$$\implies i\ln \left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)=2\tan^{-1} x$$

> **Question**:
> Is this valid?

> If yes then can someone give more examples which lead to such relations?

Thanks!

Comment: Judging from your calculations, you seem to have argued correctly. But to check it yourself, just plug it in in $\tan(x)$, using its complex representation with $e^{ix}$,( i.e. $-i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$) and see if your expression is indeed the inverse of $\tan(x)$ :)

Comment: the real part of the left side must $ \Re \left(i\ln \left(\frac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)\right)=2\tan^{-1}x$ and $Im =0$

Comment: The step when you introduce $\log$ function is a direct consequence of the definition of $\log z$ for complex values of $z$. And once you have that it is a simple matter to link $\log$ with $\tan^{-1}$.

Comment: It’s probably not a good idea to use $\mathbb C$ as your constant of integration since this almost always denotes the set of complex numbers…

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,\,\mathsf{y=tan^{-1}(x)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,x=tan(y)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,x=\dfrac{sin(y)}{cos(y)}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,x=\dfrac{\dfrac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}}{\dfrac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{2}}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,x=\dfrac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{i\left(e^{iy}+e^{-iy}\right)}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,ix=\dfrac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,\dfrac{1}{ix}=\dfrac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}}$

Using componendo and dividendo,

$\mathsf{\implies\,\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}=\dfrac{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}+e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{e^{iy}+e^{-iy}-e^{iy}+e^{-iy}}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}=\dfrac{2\,e^{iy}}{2\,e^{-iy}}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}=\dfrac{e^{iy}}{e^{-iy}}}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}=e^{2iy}}$

Taking log both sides,

$\mathsf{\implies\,\ln\left(\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)=\ln\left(e^{2iy}\right)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,\ln\left(\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)=2iy}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,y=\dfrac{1}{2\,i}\ln\left(\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,y=-\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{1+ix}{1-ix}\right)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,y=\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)}$

$\mathsf{\implies\,tan^{-1}(x)=\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\left(\dfrac{1-ix}{1+ix}\right)}$